# How to customize the library and replace it in react?

Tags: reactjs

How to customize the library and replace it in react?

I installed the library via yarn, went to the github of this library, cloned it to myself, changed everything I needed, did build and changed the folder to node_modules/MY_LIB/dist, but still nothing changed...

What am I doing wrong? Why aren't my changes still there?

[image]

Comment: Can you add some more context? How are you using/importing the code you changed?

Comment: @Hoopra I change what I need in the source library, do yarn build, and change the resulting files in my react application

Comment: That sounds like it could work, but it's hard to debug without more information. I suggest you add an example of an import, an example of the code you changed and then describe what you see vs what you expected to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want to just test it locally**, then you can use `npm link` command for this. Here are the steps

1. Go to library folder in a terminal
2. Build your library
3. do `npm link`
4. `cd` to your application folder
5. do `npm link ${library_name}` (`library_name` is the `name` field from package.json of your library)
6. Build and serve your application

This will install the local copy of the library for your application

**If you want to deploy the app with this modified version of the library**, then you can either

1. Publish it as an npm package
2. OR, you can push your version of the library to git, and install the package directly from git